# Catalog Category permissions keeps on changing automatically in Magento 2.4.1 Enterprise Edition

Tags: category-products, permissions, file-permissions, magento2-enterprise, visibility

We are using Magento 2.4.1 Enterprise Edition. Suddenly our built-in catalog category permissions keeps on changing automatically (**category permissions are set to "Deny"**). which caused PLP and PDP 404 error page issues. Whenever we change permissions manually from admin settings, after some time they are Auto reverted or changed totally. same issue for the magento directories permissions, they also keeps on changing within time.

Can someone help me out of this issue ?

Comment: Did you find the reason? We've seen the same today in a Cloud project

Comment: @RaulSanchez yes, the issue was coming due to shared catalog keeps changing and re-indexing was not running after shared catalog changes.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how is your environment build and which integrations exist, but I suspect a custom code development or a 3rd party integration which updates the categories data (and reverts or is unaware of category permissions and fallsback to a default value settings) like a cron or a script that does so, moreover since you mentioned that file permissions also change. This indicates an external process which might be executed with a different user than the webserver one.

So I suggest you check all your existing integrations, crons and automated jobs that are currently running on your Magento install.

Comment: No, it was not due to any custom or 3rd party integrations, it was due to shared catalog was changing but re indexing was not running after change, so shared catalog was restoring the catalog permissions to previous indexed stage.